Function of random variables: Conditions for finite moments
Given a real random variable $x$ and a real-valued deterministic function $f$, I am investigating the conditions such that $f(x)$ has finite moments for all orders.
Obvious sufficient conditions are

$x$ has finite moments for all orders;
$f$ is a polynomial function.

I could make the above condition more general by modifying the 2nd condition into

$f$ is polynomially bounded, i.e., $|f^k(x)| <= c |x|^k$ for some c and any k.

Is it possible to find more general conditions?
